# How can I convert this text date in Excel which will be imported into Access?

Tags: excel, ms-access, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with a text column containing a value like this:

```
13:09:23 01 JUL 2011
```

I'm importing this spreadsheet into an Access database, where I need the type to be Date/Time and look like this:

```
7/1/2011 1:09:23 PM
```

Would it be easier to change it in Excel before importing it, or deal with it in Access after the import?

I tried adding a new column (B) in Excel and put `=DATEVALUE(A1)` in B1 which gives me the date correctly. I then tried formatting the column as different Date types, but they all ignore the time and just show 12:00 AM.

How can I get both the date AND time in the format I listed above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=datevalue(A1) + timevalue(A1)
```

Comment: This worked great, and showed up as I expected it after importing the .xls into Access. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

set a formula to read `=TEXT("YOUR Cell ref","m/d/yyyy h:MM:ss AM/PM")` which will force your format.

Comment: This did the job in Excel, but when I imported the .xls into Access it didn't pull the data into the Date/Time field. But thanks for the response!